# Prove that $f(x)$ differentiable if $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Can you help me please  I could not figure this out.

Given:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f'(0)$ exists, $f(x)\neq0$ and for all $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$

How to prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Try writing down the difference quotient and see if you can transform the term.

Comment: As a concrete example, think of $f(x)=k^x, k>0$

Comment: Note that from $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)f(0)$ and $f(x)\neq0$ we get that $f(0)=1$. Then $f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a)f(h)-f(a)}{h}=f(a)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}=f(a)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f(a)f'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $f(0) = 1$. Next, for any real number $x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} &= \frac{f(x)f(h) - f(x)}{h} \\
&= f(x)\frac{f(h) - 1}{h} \\
&= f(x)\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}
\end{align}
$$
and the latter goes to $f(x)f'(0)$ as $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(0)$ exists, there is $\delta >0$ such that $f$ is continuous on $(-\delta,\delta)$. Since $f > 0$ (why), we can take $\ln$ both sides getting: $\ln(f(a+b)) = \ln(f(a)) + \ln(f(b))$. Take $ g = \ln \circ f $

We have $g(a+b) = g(a) + g(b)$ and we know that $g$ is continuous on $(-\delta,\delta)$, and since $g$ is linear, it is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Now it is an exercise from analysis to check, that only continuous solutions to this are $g(x) = Cx$ where $C \in \mathbb R$ is a constant.

We do it this way:
$g(0+0) = 2g(0)$ so $g(0) = 0$
$g(2a) = 2g(a)$, and by induction one can take $g(na) = ng(a)$, for any $a \in \mathbb R$.

Then take $g(a-a) = g(a) + g(-a)$, so $g(a) = -g(-a)$, and we have: for any $a \in \mathbb R, k \in \mathbb Z$ $g(ka) = kg(a)$.

Now we go to rationals: take any $p,q \in \mathbb Z, a \in \mathbb R$.

We have $pg(a) = pg(\frac{q}{q}a) = pq g(\frac{a}{q}) = q g(\frac{ap}{q})$, so $\frac{p}{q}g(a) = g(a\frac{p}{q})$.

We showed that for any $a \in \mathbb R, r \in \mathbb Q$ we have $g(ra) = rg(a)$. And now by continuity, one have $g(xa) = xg(a)$ for any $x,a \in \mathbb R$.

Take $a=1$, we have $g(x) = xg(1) = Cx$, where $C=g(1) = \ln(f(1))$ is some constant.

And we have $g(x) = \ln(f(x))$, so $f(x) = e^{Cx}$ and it clearly is differentiable.

Comment: THANKS A LOT !!